# Find consecutive sequence and suggest next number in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a procedure that will:

- take any number as an input e.g. `102`
- find the sequence range it belongs e.g. `100 to 103`
- return a suggested next number to the user e.g. `104`

The table itself will look something like this:

| Num |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 101 |
| 102 |
| 103 |
| 110 |
| 111 |
| 112 |
| 113 |
| 114 |
| 115 |
| 120 |
| 121 |

Ideally the output of the query would return something like this:

| start | end | nextNr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 103 | 104 |
| 110 | 115 | 116 |
| 120 | 121 | 122 |

I this what I'm trying to do is linked to some kind of Gap and Island technique.
I had a look at trying something from here but couldn't quite get it to work.
[Gaps and Islands Link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/gaps-islands-sql-server-data/)

This is what I tried coming up with...

```
WITH cteSource(ID, Seq, Num)
AS(
    SELECT d.ID, f.Seq, f.Num
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MIN(SeqNo)) AS Grp,
            MIN(SeqNo) AS StartSeqNo,
            MAX(SeqNo) AS EndSeqNo
        FROM
            (
            SELECT 1 ID, Num SeqNo, 
               Num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Num) AS RN
            FROM 
            Number
            ) AS a
        GROUP BY ID, RN
        ) d
    CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (d.Grp, d.EndSeqNo + 1),(d.Grp -1, d.StartSeqNo -1)
            ) AS f(Seq, Num)
)
SELECT ID, MIN(Num) AS StartSeqNo, MAX(Num) AS EndSeqNo, MAX(Num) + 1 as NextNr
FROM cteSource
GROUP BY ID, Seq
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The result looks like this:

| StartSeqNo | EndSeqNo | NextNr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 109 | 110 |
| 116 | 119 | 120 |

Here's the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Number](
    [Num] [int] NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO Number
(Num)
VALUES
(100),
(101),
(102),
(103),
(110),
(111),
(112),
(113),
(114),
(115),
(120),
(121)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.

```
Select [Start]  = min(num)
      ,[End]    = max(num)
      ,[NextNr] = max(num) + 1
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = num - row_number() over (order by num)
         From  number
      ) A
 Group By Grp
```

**Results**

```
Start   End     NextNr
100     103     104
110     115     116
120     121     122
```

Comment: That's just ... brilliant!

Comment: wow so simple... how would I ensure the `NextNr` doesn't accidentally run into the next sequence? Only realised this could happen after I posted....

Comment: @Justin If NextNr could run into next sequence that would mean there is no gap there and resulting sequence would not look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your first subquery works fine to get groups and start and end number:

```
  SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MIN(SeqNo)) AS Grp,
            MIN(SeqNo) AS StartSeqNo,
            MAX(SeqNo) AS EndSeqNo
        FROM
            (
            SELECT 1 ID, Num SeqNo, 
               Num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Num) AS RN
            FROM 
            Number
            ) AS a
        GROUP BY ID, RN
```

You just then needlessly complicated it instead of just using EndSeqNo + 1 for NextNr:

```
WITH CTE_Groups AS 
(
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY MIN(SeqNo)) AS Grp,
            MIN(SeqNo) AS StartSeqNo,
            MAX(SeqNo) AS EndSeqNo
        FROM
            (
            SELECT 1 ID, Num SeqNo, 
               Num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Num) AS RN
            FROM 
            Number
            ) AS a
        GROUP BY ID, RN
)
SELECT *, EndSeqNo + 1 AS NextNr 
FROM 
CTE_Groups
```

EDIT: and with further removing unnecessary partitons and extra columns

```
WITH CTE_Groups AS 
(
        SELECT 
            MIN(SeqNo) AS StartSeqNo,
            MAX(SeqNo) AS EndSeqNo
        FROM
            (
            SELECT  Num SeqNo, 
               Num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Num) AS RN
            FROM 
            Number
            ) AS a
        GROUP BY RN
)
SELECT *, EndSeqNo + 1 AS NextNr 
FROM 
CTE_Groups
```